# When Semaphore.availablePermits() can return more than declared in constructor?

Tags: java, concurrency

In JDK6, under which circumstances can `Semaphore.availablePermits() > x`, where x is value provided in `new Semaphore(x)`?

Does this mean that `Semaphore.release()` was called more times than `Semaphore.tryAcquire()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that does mean that `Semaphore.release()` was called more times than any of the permit-acquiring methods (including but not limited to `tryAquire()`) . Specifically, it means that some thread(s) released permit(s) that were never acquired.

However, this may in fact be a perfectly normal situation. If somehow more resources become available to perform the action, it would make perfect sense for the thread responsible for tracking that to add additional permits to the pool.